# Changing Values in a xml file

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I am trying to change numerous values in a xml document. I have tried to a couple different things but they dont seem to change anything but they do seem to access the file as the modification time changes but the value doesnt.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
import os
import xml

path = os.path.expanduser(r'~\AppData\Roaming\etc\etc\somefile.xml')
et = et.parse(path)

for name in et.findall('name'):
    if name == 'sometext1':
        name.text = "sometext2"
et.write(path)
```

and secondly tried this but I get a AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

```
with open(path,'r+') as f:
tree = et.parse(f)

for node in tree.iter('favourite'):
name = node.attrib.get('name')

if name == 'sometext1':
    name.text = "sometext2"
tree.write(path)
```

Could anyone advise where Ive gone wrong

Comment: `name` is the element's name. `node` is the element.

Answer (score 0):

- The line

  ```
  et = et.parse(path)
  ```

  uses `et` as a module on the right and as a variable name on the
  left. After this point, it is not possible (or at least overly hard)
  to access the ElementTree module. So disambiguate `et`. Let, say,
  `ET` be the module, and `tree` be the `ElementTree`.
- In the for loop, `name` is an Element, so comparing `name` to a
  string will always be False. Instead use

  ```
  name.text == 'sometext1'
  ```

---

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import os

path = os.path.expanduser(r'~\AppData\Roaming\etc\etc\somefile.xml')
tree = ET.parse(path)

for name in tree.findall('name'):
    if name.text == 'sometext1':
        name.text = "sometext2"
        print(name) # for debugging only
tree.write(path)
```

Comment: I have tried these changes but still no changes happen to the xml file.

Comment: Are you sure `tree.findall('name')` is finding elements? Try putting a `print` statement in the loop so you can see if elements are being found. (One reason `<name>` elements might not be found is because you might need to reference it in a [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).)